Неисправно работает интернет. Программы не включаются
Не могу войти в программы на компьютере.  Везде пишет нет подключения.  В стиме - "для обновления steam должен быть онлайн 2023". В Battle.net - Не удалось авторизоваться ... В Hide.Me "Ваш запрос не может быть обработан" , в торренте Бесконечное подключение к пирам идёт  и т.д
В браузере только интернет работает. Переустановка этих программ не помогает.  С Брандмауэром поработал.  Никаких изменений. Вирусов нет.
PHP стал писать ошибку при запуске

php -S localhost:8000

Failed to listen on localhost:8000 reeason: php_network_getaddress: getaddrinfo for localhost failed

Произошло это после того как я диск переделал в динамический случайно. И  пытался установить Kali Linux с раздела жесткого диска.

Ответ очевиден. Вам давно пора как следует переустановить ОС. С таким набором данных Вам никто ничем не поможет. Телепортировать и читать мысли системщики не умеют. Если Вы не умеет это делать за сущие гроши Вам это сделают системщики по объявлению. Дольше писать комменты будете.

А что у вас в hosts прописано?

Переустановка Виндоус помогла.
